# Sizing textarea inside kendo grid

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

I need an inline textarea inside a kendo grid to allow the user to edit a string value. I want to use a textarea because the value can be quite long. I am using a custom editor to achieve this like mentioned here: http://www.telerik.com/forums/how-to-change-input-to-textarea-in-popup-editor

I am setting the width and height of the textarea to be the same as the container's

```
$('<textarea data-text-field="Label" data-value-field="Value" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '" style="width: ' + container.width() + 'px;height:' + container.height() + 'px" />')
```

This doesn't seem to work. When I inspect the height of the textarea element in my developer tools before I click on the cell to edit, it shows as 35px and after as 47px. This causes the rest of the grid to move down.

http://dojo.telerik.com/@unicorn2/eCAkU

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That happens because you can't just use the `container`'s height as height of an element inside itself, in that case. The row has other *spacing* properties like padding, for instance. In a simple and quick shot I came through this:

```
$('<textarea data-text-field="Label" data-value-field="Value" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '" style="width: ' + (container.width() - 10) + 'px;height:' + (container.height() - 12) + 'px" />').appendTo(container);
```

[Demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/IsUvAp/).

Just by decreasing a little the container's dimensions it fits the row height very nice. The only problem is with break lines, because when the `editor` callback is called, the content of the container is reset and the row's height becomes like if was a single line. Then the `container.height()` returns a single line height.